# Ordering Postgres Results by name clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

So I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM accounts
WHERE firstname = "Tom Bill"
  OR (firstname = "Tom" AND middlename = "Bill")
  OR (firstname = "Bill" AND middlename = "Tom");
```

My goal is to get the query to order itself in this manner:

```
All Tom Bill first
All Tom + Bill second 
All Bill + Tom third
```

Is it possible to construct a query that will do this or do I need to handle this ordering in the controller?

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Can you give sample input data and output data you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN firstname = "Tom Bill" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN firstname = "Tom" AND middlename = "Bill" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN firstname = "Bill" AND middlename = "Tom" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

You can also write this as:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN firstname = "Tom Bill" THEN 0
              WHEN firstname = "Tom" AND middlename = "Bill" THEN 1
              WHEN firstname = "Bill" AND middlename = "Tom" THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END;
```

Comment: Ok I am going to give that a try, this looks great though thanks for getting back so quickly I will update you shortly

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this in SQL by building a case statement. Based on your where clause, it could be simplified to:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN firstname = "Tom Bill" THEN 0
              WHEN firstname = "Tom" THEN 1
              ELSE 2 END
```

Methinks you'll usually be better off by ordering this kind of stuff in your controller, however, because generating the needed case statement (be it in an ORM or not), while simple, tends to be a bit messy.

---

> this is going to be running a search on a database with 1 million + accounts, So I believe that doing it in the query is best. Please let me know if you desagree

It depends on the number of rows you're returning.

If, as I'm suspecting based on your example data, you're scanning for dup data, you'll be dealing with a handful of rows each time. In that case, sorting in your app is just as good if not better: it frees CPU cycles on the DB server, and it allows you to use any number of convoluted sort criteria if your final intent is to merge rows automatically.

If, on the other hand, your query is returning a gazillion rows, you probably shouldn't be ordering by a case statement to begin with: doing so prevents you from using a proper index, so these queries will promptly creep into your slow query logs. Create an additional field (how about `sort_name` or `display_name`?), index it, amend your DB and app logic accordingly, and use that instead.

Comment: If you need the top 5 records of 10k, relying on a controller is not going to work...

Comment: @PinnyM: True, but if you need the top-5 of 10k, you should definitely not be ordering by a case statement either. :-) I imagine OP is looking into merging duplicate users, so the number should be slow enough.

Comment: Re: CASE statement for 10k - not for general use, but as an ad-hoc paged report, this is a common scenario.

Comment: So actually this is going to be running a search on a database with 1 million + accounts, So I believe that doing it in the query is best. Please let me know if you desagree